# Using Angular list with two columns

Tags: angular, mat-list

How can I use [angular lists](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview) with two columns of text on left and right?

The basic example shown on the angular website is the following:

```
<mat-list>
 <mat-list-item> Pepper </mat-list-item>
 <mat-list-item> Salt </mat-list-item>
 <mat-list-item> Paprika </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

I want to split the text in each `<mat-list-item>` to show on two columns (left and right aligned)

I tried a couple of ways including:

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item>
         <p style="float:left">Left Text</p>
         <p style="float:right">Right Text</p>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item>
         <p style="float:left">Left Text</p>
         <p style="float:right">Right Text</p>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

but none seem to work.

How can I achieve this without using grid lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the `matLine` in you code to make it work. Try like this, It will work.

```
<mat-list>
     <mat-list-item >
      <div matLine>
          <p style="float:left">Left Text</p>
          <p style="float:right">Right Text</p>
         </div>
     </mat-list-item>
     <mat-list-item>
        <div matLine>
          <p style="float:left">Left Text</p>
          <p style="float:right">Right Text</p>
        </div>
   </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `mat-grid-list`. For example,

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item> Pepper </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item> Salt </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item> Pepper </mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item> Salt </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

If this looks complex for you, you can easily use basic `bootstrap grids` for dividing into two columns. For example,

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col col-6>
   // You can put your left items here
 </div>
 <div class="col col-6>
  // You can put your right items here
 </div>
</div>
```